# Cancel order item without cancelling order in magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order

How to cancel order item without cancelling order in magento 2? Is it possible

Comment: you want to multile item to decress the qty in order after placing order ?

Comment: Yes. Decrease quantity and and remove a product.

Comment: you can only decrease quantity not delete product. so